# Mysql: Need Following Output

Tags: mysql, sql, select, grouping, ranking

I have 2 Tables `StudentEnrollmentDetails` and `StudentExamAnalysis`. Using these 2 Table I need following output.

```
SchoolId Rank StudentName Percentage
1        1    ABC         70
1        2    ABD         69.56
1        3    ABC         69
2        1    ABC         71
2        2    ABD         68.56
2        3    ABC         63
```

I have a basic query. I need to generate rank on the Fly.

```
SELECT SED.SchoolId, @s:=@s+1 serial_number, SAED.*
FROM StudentAnswerExamData SAED INNER JOIN StudentEnrollmentDetails SED ON SED.StudentEnrollmentDetailsId = SAED.StudentEnrollmentDetailsId
INNER JOIN (SELECT @s:= 0) AS s
WHERE SED.ExamCategoryId = 2 AND SED.ExamId = 2 AND SED.Standard = 5 AND SED.CompanyId = 2
ORDER BY SED.SchoolId, SAED.Percentage DESC;
```

`Table Definition`
`Table: studentenrollmentdetails`
`FIELD                       TYPE`

---

`StudentEnrollmentDetailsId BIGINT(20)

StudentId                   BIGINT(20)

StudentRegNo                BIGINT(20)

ExamCategoryId              INT(11)

ExamId                      BIGINT(20)

SchoolId                    BIGINT(20)

SourceId                    BIGINT(20)

SourceAccountId             BIGINT(20)

Standard                    INT(11)

Amount                      DECIMAL(10,2) 
IsOptionEnabled             TINYINT(1)

ExamSessionId               BIGINT(20)

EnrollmentFormPath          VARCHAR(300)

Division                    VARCHAR(10)

TransactionTime             DATETIME

CompanyId                   INT(11)

STATUS                      INT(11)

UploadedBy                  BIGINT(20)

FileId                      BIGINT(20)

LastModifiedBy              BIGINT(20)

LastModifiedByTime          DATETIME

SchoolName                  VARCHAR(100)

SchoolLocation              VARCHAR(100)

MarkForDelete               TINYINT(1)`

`Table: studentanswerexamdata`
`Column Information`
`FIELD                       TYPE`

---

`StudentAnswerExamDataId     BIGINT(20)

StudentId                   BIGINT(20)

StudentEnrollmentDetailsId  BIGINT(20)

ExamCategoryId              INT(10)

ExamId                      BIGINT(20)

Standard                    INT(10)

CompanyId                   INT(10)

UploadedById                BIGINT(20)

UploadedDateTime            DATETIME

ModifiedById                BIGINT(20)

ModifiedDateTime            DATETIME

MarkForDelete               TINYINT(1)

SeatNo                      BIGINT(20)

NoOfCorrect                 INT(11)

NoOfInCorrect               INT(11)

NoOfMissing                 INT(11)

MarksScored                 DECIMAL(6,2)

Percentage                  DECIMAL(5,2)

SchoolRank                  INT(11)

DistrictRank                INT(11)

StateRank                   INT(11)

NationalRank            INT`

Comment: Great. And I need {..whatever..} - where are your tables definition? Where are sample of input data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *, (IF(@schoolId=@schoolId:=A.schoolId, @s:=@s+1, @s:=1)) serial_number
FROM (SELECT SED.SchoolId, SAED.*
      FROM StudentAnswerExamData SAED 
      INNER JOIN StudentEnrollmentDetails SED ON SED.StudentEnrollmentDetailsId =   SAED.StudentEnrollmentDetailsId
      WHERE SED.ExamCategoryId = 2 AND SED.ExamId = 2 AND SED.Standard = 5 AND 
            SED.CompanyId = 2
      ORDER BY SED.SchoolId, SAED.Percentage DESC
    ) AS A, (SELECT @s:=1, @schoolId:=0) AS s;
```

Check this Link [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b3ce/12)

**OUTPUT**

```
| SCHOOLID | STUDENTANSWEREXAMDATAID | STUDENTID | STUDENTENROLLMENTDETAILSID | EXAMCATEGORYID | EXAMID | STANDARD | COMPANYID | UPLOADEDBYID |               UPLOADEDDATETIME | MODIFIEDBYID |               MODIFIEDDATETIME | MARKFORDELETE |     SEATNO | NOOFCORRECT | NOOFINCORRECT | NOOFMISSING | MARKSSCORED | PERCENTAGE | SCHOOLRANK | DISTRICTRANK | STATERANK | NATIONALRANK | PROCESSEDSTATUS | FILEPATH | @S:=1 | @SCHOOLID:=0 | SERIAL_NUMBER |
|----------|-------------------------|-----------|----------------------------|----------------|--------|----------|-----------|--------------|--------------------------------|--------------|--------------------------------|---------------|------------|-------------|---------------|-------------|-------------|------------|------------|--------------|-----------|--------------|-----------------|----------|-------|--------------|---------------|
|       23 |                       4 |      1546 |                       2044 |              2 |      2 |        5 |         2 |            5 | January, 28 2014 15:01:13+0000 |            1 | January, 29 2014 11:19:35+0000 |             0 | 1023052901 |          38 |            37 |           0 |         113 |      75.33 |         -1 |           -1 |        -1 |           -1 |               1 |   (null) |     1 |            0 |             1 |
|       54 |                       6 |      1557 |                       2055 |              2 |      2 |        5 |         2 |            5 | January, 28 2014 15:01:13+0000 |            1 | January, 29 2014 11:19:35+0000 |             0 | 1054052901 |          25 |            46 |           4 |          96 |         64 |         -1 |           -1 |        -1 |           -1 |               1 |   (null) |     1 |            0 |             1 |
|       56 |                      16 |      1550 |                       2048 |              2 |      2 |        5 |         2 |            5 | January, 28 2014 15:01:13+0000 |            1 | January, 29 2014 11:19:35+0000 |             0 | 1056052903 |          36 |            39 |           0 |         111 |         74 |         -1 |           -1 |        -1 |           -1 |               1 |   (null) |     1 |            0 |             1 |
|       56 |                      15 |      1549 |                       2047 |              2 |      2 |        5 |         2 |            5 | January, 28 2014 15:01:13+0000 |            1 | January, 29 2014 11:19:35+0000 |             0 | 1056052902 |          30 |            43 |           2 |         103 |      68.67 |         -1 |           -1 |        -1 |           -1 |               1 |   (null) |     1 |            0 |             2 |
|       56 |                      13 |      1548 |                       2046 |              2 |      2 |        5 |         2 |            5 | January, 28 2014 15:01:13+0000 |            1 | January, 29 2014 11:19:35+0000 |             0 | 1056052901 |          27 |            48 |           0 |         102 |         68 |         -1 |           -1 |        -1 |           -1 |               1 |   (null) |     1 |            0 |             3 |
|       74 |                       7 |      1551 |                       2049 |              2 |      2 |        5 |         2 |            5 | January, 28 2014 15:01:13+0000 |            1 | January, 29 2014 11:19:35+0000 |             0 | 1074052901 |          21 |            54 |           0 |          96 |         64 |         -1 |           -1 |        -1 |           -1 |               1 |   (null) |     1 |            0 |             1 |
|       78 |                       8 |      1558 |                       2056 |              2 |      2 |        5 |         2 |            5 | January, 28 2014 15:01:13+0000 |            1 | January, 29 2014 11:19:35+0000 |             0 | 1078052901 |          37 |            38 |           0 |         112 |      74.67 |         -1 |           -1 |        -1 |           -1 |               1 |   (null) |     1 |            0 |             1 |
|      108 |                       9 |      1547 |                       2045 |              2 |      2 |        5 |         2 |            5 | January, 28 2014 15:01:13+0000 |            1 | January, 29 2014 11:19:35+0000 |             0 | 1108052901 |          26 |            46 |           3 |          98 |      65.33 |         -1 |           -1 |        -1 |           -1 |               1 |   (null) |     1 |            0 |             1 |
|      114 |                      10 |      1555 |                       2053 |              2 |      2 |        5 |         2 |            5 | January, 28 2014 15:01:13+0000 |            1 | January, 29 2014 11:19:35+0000 |             0 | 1114052901 |          28 |            47 |           0 |         103 |      68.67 |         -1 |           -1 |        -1 |           -1 |               1 |   (null) |     1 |            0 |             1 |
|      133 |                       5 |      1556 |                       2054 |              2 |      2 |        5 |         2 |            5 | January, 28 2014 15:01:13+0000 |            1 | January, 29 2014 11:19:35+0000 |             0 | 1133052901 |          44 |            29 |           2 |         117 |         78 |         -1 |           -1 |        -1 |           -1 |               1 |   (null) |     1 |            0 |             1 |
|      160 |                       3 |      1552 |                       2050 |              2 |      2 |        5 |         2 |            5 | January, 28 2014 15:01:13+0000 |            1 | January, 29 2014 11:19:35+0000 |             0 | 1160052901 |          25 |            50 |           0 |         100 |      66.67 |         -1 |           -1 |        -1 |           -1 |               1 |   (null) |     1 |            0 |             1 |
|      164 |                      14 |      1553 |                       2051 |              2 |      2 |        5 |         2 |            5 | January, 28 2014 15:01:13+0000 |            1 | January, 29 2014 11:19:35+0000 |             0 | 1164052901 |          32 |            43 |           0 |         107 |      71.33 |         -1 |           -1 |        -1 |           -1 |               1 |   (null) |     1 |            0 |             1 |
|      170 |                      17 |      1554 |                       2052 |              2 |      2 |        5 |         2 |            5 | January, 28 2014 15:01:13+0000 |            1 | January, 29 2014 11:19:35+0000 |             0 | 1170052901 |          12 |            15 |          48 |          39 |         26 |         -1 |           -1 |        -1 |           -1 |               1 |   (null) |     1 |            0 |             1 |
|      324 |                      12 |      1560 |                       2058 |              2 |      2 |        5 |         2 |            5 | January, 28 2014 15:01:13+0000 |            1 | January, 29 2014 11:19:35+0000 |             0 | 1324052902 |          41 |            32 |           2 |         114 |         76 |         -1 |           -1 |        -1 |           -1 |               1 |   (null) |     1 |            0 |             1 |
|      324 |                      11 |      1559 |                       2057 |              2 |      2 |        5 |         2 |            5 | January, 28 2014 15:01:13+0000 |            1 | January, 29 2014 11:19:35+0000 |             0 | 1324052901 |          29 |            33 |          13 |          91 |      60.67 |         -1 |           -1 |        -1 |           -1 |               1 |   (null) |     1 |            0 |             2 |
```

Comment: Thanx. But Rank for all is same i.e. 1.

Comment: This was the Output
`SchoolId | serial_number | Percentage
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
56       | 2             | 74.00
56       | 1             | 68.67
56       | 1             | 68.00`

This is not the expected output. I was also struggling here.